# Console widget for Python bokeh application

Tags: python, bokeh, tornado

Below is a minimal example of a `bokeh` application that updates the text of a `Div` object after a `Button` object is clicked.  The idea is to get the text of the `Div` object to update synchronously with text in the console running the application, and the subsequent goal is to develop something like a *console widget* that can be embedded in a `bokeh` application to let users know status of backend processes.

I understand that a `bokeh` application can only send data updates when control is returned back to the server event loop ([this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745065/force-update-of-bokeh-widgets)), so the code below does not update the `Div` text synchronously with text in the console.  Is there a simple way to achieve this specific use case?

```
from bokeh.models import Button, Div
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from numpy.random import permutation
from time import sleep

def update():
    for _ in range(4):
        # shuffle text
        text = ''.join(permutation(list('abcd')))
        print(text)
        div.text = text
        sleep(0.5)

div = Div(background='grey', text='', width=100, height=50)
button = Button(label='update', width=50)
button.on_click(update)

curdoc().add_root(row(button, div))
```

**Initial app**

[image: initial app]

**app after clicking update Button**

[image: final app]

**console running app**

[image: console]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196855/python-bokeh-markup-text-value-cant-update/59199773#59199773 is also relevant

Comment: CLIs are a complex topic, especially when the underlying library was never intended to be used that way. If you really want to see `dcba` be replaced with `cdba` in the console output above, take a look at how the `progress` library implements it.